# how to embed external js script file into react component

Tags: reactjs

I can add this file into react component but widget appears under the page. not in the div in render method no style can change its position.

https://www.tradingview.com/widget/market-movers/

```
  componentWillMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    const script2 = document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
      "https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-market-overview.js";
    script2.src =
      "https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-hotlists.js";
    script.async = true;
    script2.async = true;
    //script.onload = () => this.scriptLoaded();

    // document.body.appendChild(script);
    // document.body.appendChild(script2);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are trying to append your new script under body element. You need to use refs and you need to append your new script with using 'componentDidMount'

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    const script2 = document.createElement("script");
    script.src =
      "https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-market-overview.js";
    script2.src =
      "https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-hotlists.js";
    script.async = true;
    script2.async = true;

    this.myRef.appendChild(script);
    this.myRef.appendChild(script2);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div
        ref={DOMNodeRef => {
          this.myRef = DOMNodeRef;
        }}
      >
        test
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-noether-qvqgj